# Execution Timeout Expired error during DACPAC (SSDT) publish using DacServices.Deploy

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

We're randomly getting the below error when publishing a dacpac using DacServices.Deploy in C#. Along with tables, the Dacpac also has a post-deployment script which is the part which is raising the timeout error. We're publishing onto a new SQL Server 2014 database (hence, not an upgrade scenario). Will anyone suggest a solution please?

PS: This typically happens on the first attempt on a new server and then works perfectly on second attempt. The DacPac publish is part of our installer and installer failure makes a bad impression.

**Error...**

> Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to
>   completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

We've explicitly set a timeout but that doesnt seem to be picked up because the publish fails in a little over a minute whereas the timeout is set to be 600 seconds.

**DacDeployer code...**

```
                var dacOptions = new DacDeployOptions();
                dacOptions.IncludeCompositeObjects = true;
                dacOptions.IncludeTransactionalScripts = true;
                dacOptions.GenerateSmartDefaults = true;
                //Specify timeout in seconds to override the default 60
                dacOptions.CommandTimeout = 600;

                using (DacPackage dacpac = DacPackage.Load(dacpacName))
                {
                    dacServiceInstance.Deploy(dacpac, DBName, upgradeExisting: true, options: dacOptions);
                }
```

**Info, Warning and Error logs returned by the event listener on DacServices.Deploy...**

```
Initializing deployment (Start)
Initializing deployment (Complete)
Analyzing deployment plan (Start)
Analyzing deployment plan (Complete)
Updating database (Start)
Creating DW_Control...
Creating [DW_INTERNAL]...
Creating [DW_INTERNAL].[DB_VERSIONS]...
Creating [DW_INTERNAL].[SCRIPT_LOG]...
Warning! The maximum key length is 900 bytes. The index 'PK_SCRIPT_LOG' has maximum length of 1102 bytes. For some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail.
Creating [DW_INTERNAL].[SCRIPT_MASTER]...
Creating [DW_INTERNAL].[SCRIPT_STATUS]...
Warning! The maximum key length is 900 bytes. The index 'PK_SCRIPT_STATUS' has maximum length of 1094 bytes. For some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail.
Creating [dbo].[ARCHIVE_STATUS]...
Creating unnamed constraint on ...
Creating [dbo].[FK_...]...
Creating [dbo].[VW_...]...
Creating [DW_INTERNAL].[ADD]...
Creating [DW_INTERNAL].[ADD_SCRIPT]...
Creating [DW_INTERNAL].[UPGRADE]...
Creating [dbo].[VW_AMOUNT_SUMMARY].[MS_Description]...
The transacted portion of the database update succeeded.
.Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg -2, Level 11, State 0, Line 0 Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
Script execution error.  The executed script:
EXECUTE DW_INTERNAL.ADD_VERSION @Module = 'CTL', @ToVersion = '1.17.02.00';

EXECUTE DW_INTERNAL.ADD_SCRIPT @Module = 'CTL', @FromVersion = '0.00.00.00', @ToVersion = '1.17.02.00', @ApplyOrder = 40, @UpgrScriptFilepath = 'CTL_0.00.00.00_1.17.02.00_P_DML.sql';

EXECUTE DW_INTERNAL.ADD_SCRIPT @Module = 'CTL', @FromVersion = '0.00.00.00', @ToVersion = '1.17.02.00', @ApplyOrder = 30, @UpgrScriptFilepath = 'CTL_0.00.00.00_1.17.02.00_R_DML.sql';

EXECUTE DW_INTERNAL.ADD_VERSION @Module = 'CTL', @ToVersion = '1.17.07.00';

EXECUTE DW_INTERNAL.ADD_SCRIPT @Module = 'CTL', @FromVersion = '1.17.02.00', @ToVersion = '1.17.07.00', @ApplyOrder = 60, @UpgrScriptFilepath = 'CTL_1.17.02.00_1.17.07.00_P_DML.sql';

EXECUTE DW_INTERNAL.ADD_SCRIPT @M
An error occurred while the batch was being executed.
Updating database (Failed)
Error details: Could not deploy package.
Error SQL72014: 

Stack Trace: at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.ThrowIfErrorManagerHasErrors()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.<>c__DisplayClass14.<>c__DisplayClass16.<CreatePlanExecutionOperation>b__13()
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Dac.OperationLogger.Capture(Action action)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.<>c__DisplayClass14.<CreatePlanExecutionOperation>b__12(Object operation, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Operation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.ReportMessageOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.OperationExtension.CompositeOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.OperationExtension.Execute(IOperation operation, DacLoggingContext loggingContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.InternalDeploy(IPackageSource packageSource, Boolean isDacpac, String targetDatabaseName, DacDeployOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken, DacLoggingContext loggingContext, Action`3 reportPlanOperation, Boolean executePlan)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.Deploy(DacPackage package, String targetDatabaseName, Boolean upgradeExisting, DacDeployOptions options, Nullable`1 cancellationToken)
   at DacDeployer.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

---

**Stored Procedure invoked...**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [DW_INTERNAL].[ADD_SCRIPT]
    @Module VARCHAR(30), 
    @FromVersion VARCHAR(20), 
    @ToVersion VARCHAR(20), 
    @ApplyOrder INT, 
    @UpgrScriptFilepath VARCHAR(1024) 

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(500);
    SET @FileName = RIGHT(@UpgrScriptFilepath, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@UpgrScriptFilepath)) - 1);

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [DW_INTERNAL].[SCRIPT_MASTER] WHERE [MODULE]=@Module AND [FROM_VERSION]=@FromVersion AND [TO_VERSION]=@ToVersion and RIGHT([UPGR_SCRIPT_FILEPATH], CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE([UPGR_SCRIPT_FILEPATH])) - 1) = @FileName)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [DW_INTERNAL].[SCRIPT_MASTER]
                   ([MODULE],
                    [FROM_VERSION],
                    [TO_VERSION],
                    [APPLY_ORDER],
                    [UPGR_SCRIPT_FILEPATH])
             VALUES
                   (@Module,
                   @FromVersion,
                   @ToVersion,
                   @ApplyOrder,
                   @UpgrScriptFilepath)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [DW_INTERNAL].[SCRIPT_MASTER]
        SET [APPLY_ORDER] = @ApplyOrder
        WHERE [MODULE]=@Module AND [FROM_VERSION]=@FromVersion AND [TO_VERSION]=@ToVersion and [UPGR_SCRIPT_FILEPATH]=@UpgrScriptFilepath
    END
END
```

Comment: is it re-producible? We sometimes get locks and timeouts, however publish restart usually helps

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that it occurs occasionally (typically the first time when installing on a new server) and works on second attempt.
The problem is that the dacpac publish is part of our installer and installer failure is a very sore first impression during demos.
PS: Will update this in the question too now!

Comment: then you need to find out what's locking the deployment. Additionally I suggest you not to use the log you provide, instead of that click on the "View results" (or something like that) in visual studio SSDT data tools output window. The window you provide not always show the exact place of failure.

Comment: Like I've mentioned, we're publishing the dacpac using DacServices.Deploy API

Comment: Anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: what does SQL Server logs say?